# Rendering native input field in Chrome on Android results in missing borders

Tags: android, css, google-chrome

For a web application I'm building I want to use the unstyled input fields as they're being rendered by Chrome. On desktop that works fine and I get nice, thin borders around the inputs, but on chrome on android the rendering of the borders is a bit fickle. Depending on the height of the page they are rendered [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U115c.png)

I've made a codepen with several options in order to try to get a consistent rendering, but none of them seem to work predictably: https://codepen.io/dianabroeders/pen/XabXPG

All options i tried to get the rendering right:

```
.input1{
  transform: scale(0.9999999);
}
.input2{
  border: 1px solid #a9a9a9;
  padding: 2px 1px;
}
.input3{
  border-image: none;
}
.input4{
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
.input5{
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

Is there a fix to reliably render an input with all borders showing, nice and thin, all the time on chrome on android and chrome on desktop? And the width and height staying the same as an unstyled input?

PS, i found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854195/chrome-default-borders-on-input-text), that helped me understand what was going on with the rendering...